# difference between method of object of mock when callbase is toggled

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nunit, moq

I have a mocked object:

```
var mockA = new Mock<AClass>();
```

AClass looks something like this:

```
public class AClass()
{
  public void someMethod()
  {
    //dostuff
  }
}
```

**what would be the difference between**

```
mockA.CallBase = false;
mockA.Object.someMethod();
```

**and this?**

```
mockA.CallBase = true;
mockA.Object.someMethod();
```

Comment: There is no inheritance in your example, so there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to expand your classes a bit more to see the usage of the CallBase property. The CallBase property allows us to inform a mocked object that we want it to invoke the base class implementation if no expectation overrides the member. So for example your AClass has a base class of BaseClass

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual string GetStatus
   {
       get{
           return "Ok";
       }
   }
}

public class AClass():BaseClass
{
   public bool someMethod()
   {
       return GetStatus == "Ok";
   }
}
```

Now if you ran your first test

```
mockA.CallBase = false;
Assert.IsTrue(mockA.Object.someMethod());
```

This would fail as call base is not called and GetStatus would not be initialised it would simply be null;

Now the second test would pass as the CallBase property is true and the GetStatus string would be initialised to "Ok".

```
mockA.CallBase = true;
Assert.IsTrue(mockA.Object.someMethod());
```